# Someone please check this code..Issue in array values?

Tags: c#, arrays

the string values are not converting to int. I'm trying to read it from a file

```
lol
1   3   10  100 30  60  UserId  
2   3   100 100 30  100 UserId
```

and I'm loaded it in a constructor

```
string[] line;

if (File.Exists(fn))
{
    try
    {
        line = File.ReadAllLines(fn);
        for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++)
        {
            if (line[i] != null)
            {
                string[] pty = line[i].Split('\t');                               
                int ID = Convert.ToInt32(pty[0]);
                ItemTypes types = (ItemTypes)int.Parse(pty[1]);
                int X = int.Parse(pty[2]);
                int Y = Convert.ToInt32(pty[3]);
                int Height = Convert.ToInt32(pty[4]);
                int Width = Convert.ToInt32(pty[5]);
                string text = pty[6].ToLower();
```

Comment: do you get an error? if so what error?

Comment: The Int values shows null and array displays real values when I break the execution.

Comment: @JRU You should debug your code to find out the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys, but is the code looks good?

Comment: @JRU, tell us where in your code does the problem occur. Where are you using the parsed values?

Comment: I'm using this parsed values to make a form.. The string loads all the correct values from the txt file. only the RHS not LHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you attempt to parse a string representation of an enum as an integer:

> `ItemTypes types = (ItemTypes)int.Parse(pty[1]);`

According to your code `pty[1]` has the value `ItemTypes.Label`, Which cannot be parsed as an integer. This cannot be parsed as an enum either. In order for your code to work, you need to store the enum values as integer - you need to replace the `ItemTypes.Label` from your input with the corresponding int value

```
(int) ItemTypes.Label
```

Alternatively you can use the [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. You still have to modify the input not to include the enum type, so that `ItemTypes.Label` becomes `Label` only:

```
ItemTypes types = (ItemTypes) Enum.Parse(typeof(ItemTypes), pty[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you , I got it the actual value for that is an integer in the file , forget to do so...but I'm still confused what might be the issue with other variables?

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you do something like this and then iterator on list

```
List<String> wordsList = new List<string>();
string[] pty = line[i].Split('\t');

foreach (string word in pty)
{
  wordsList.Add(word);
}
```

you are not doing wrong, the only big mistake is that ItemTypes.Label cant be parsed to Int32 as mentioned by @Ivaylo Slavov